# How to handle successive https request in node JS?

Tags: node.js, oauth, callback, slack, asynccallback

I'm trying to build a slack app and to configure it properly I need to do successive Https get request. I use callbacks methods to handle it, the first one calls the second one without any problem but then the third one never starts, and my program is stuck.
Here is my code :

```js
//CREATE THE app OBJECT
//---------------------

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;



//CALLBACK FUNCTIONS
//------------------

// USE THE SLACK BUTTON TO CREATE THE APP
boutonSlack = function(req, res,next) { 
    res.send('<a href="https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=bot,incoming-webhook,commands&client_id='+process.env.CLIENT_ID+'">' 
                +'<img alt="Add to Slack" height="40" width="139"'
                +'src="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png" '
                +'srcset="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, '
                +'https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x" /></a>');
    console.log('cb0:le bouton slack s\'affiche');
    next();
    app.get('/redirect/',oauthFlow);
};


//GET THE CODE PARAMETER AND PERFORM THE OAUTH FLOW
oauthFlow = function(req, res, next){
    process.env.CODE = req.query.code;
    console.log('cb1 : le code est récupéré');
    https.get('https://slack.com/api/oauth.access?client_id='+process.env.CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+process.env.CLIENT_SECRET+'&code='+process.env.CODE, (res) => {
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            var result = JSON.parse(chunk);
            process.env.SLACKTOKEN = result.access_token;
            process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = result.bot.bot_access_token;
            console.log('cb2 : le token est récupéré')
            next();
            app.get('/websocket/',ouvertureWebsocket);
        });
    });
};


//THIS CALLBACK NEVER STARTS
//PERFORM THE rtm.slack METHOD
ouvertureWebsocket = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("working");
    https.get('https://slack.com/api/rtm.start?token='+process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN, (res) => {
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            var result = JSON.parse(chunk);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            console.log('cb3 : ouverture du web socket');
            next();
        });
    });
    res.end(); 
}



//RUN THE CALLBACK FUNCTIONS
//--------------------------

app.get('/',boutonSlack);
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Ready, listenning port '+port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This raises suspicions:

```
app.get('/redirect/',oauthFlow);
```

not that theres anything wrong with the code line, it's just that its inside a handler for the `'/'` route. Normally you'd define all route handlers on the top level and not anymore in any handlers.

Comment: That would explain why it find this trying to execute my code.
Cannot GET /redirect/?code=<MYCODEHERE>&state=
How can I define all the route handlers at a top level?

Comment: Just move the `app.get('/redirect/',oauthFlow);` line from inside the handler to the top level after `app.get('/',boutonSlack);` for example.